# How can I .htaccess rewrite file path

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a common header file which has included the CSS, JS, JQuery which I include in every PHP file.  Now I have a folder "X" which I have written the below .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /default/x/

RewriteRule default.css ../css/default.css
RewriteRule /js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js ../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
RewriteRule /js/jquery.corner.js ../js/jquery.corner.js
RewriteRule /js/default.js ../js/default.js


RewriteRule $ state.php
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to get the path of the JS and CSS correctly.  Its showing up as /`host/x/css/default.css & /host/x/js/default.js` instead of `/host/css/default.css & /host/js/default.js`.

But the header.php include is coming properly.  I can read the DB login requirement from the header.php.

Any idea how to correct the file path?

Comment: Fix where the css and js files are loaded from. If you load jquery from both `/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` and `/x/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` the client thinks it is dealing with 2 different files and loads them twice and caches them twice. Instead make sure that the url you are loading it from is not relative to the folder in the url bar, but to the domain root instead.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Did not work out.  I even gave http://localhost/x/js/jquery.min.js in the .htaccess.

Comment: I mean that you should have `href="/css/default.css"` in your header file and `href="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"`, not `href="css/default.css"` and `href="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"`.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Can you post this as the answer?